# Ошибка в переводе формата даты pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, datetime

Коллеги,

помогите с ошибкой в корректный перевод даты.

Есть датафрейм:

df:

```
name  date
Fora  08.04.2019 14:04
Jara  17.12.2018 17:29
Aura  04.07.2018 16:40
```

все типы изначально non-null object

Следующим кодом я хочу корректно изменить тип date как формату даты, но при этом сохранить изначальный вид даты:

```
df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date']).dt.strftime('%d.%m.%Y')
```

Однако у меня получается в результате следующий казус в переформатировании:

```
name  date
Fora  04.08.2019 
Jara  17.12.2018 
Aura  07.04.2018
```

т.е. то что должно быть днем стало месяцем :((( Буду признателен за подсказку, как это сделать грамотно и без ошибок!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

А ещё есть параметр `format`:

```
df["date"] = pd.to_datetime(df["date"], format="%d.%m.%Y", dayfirst=True)


   name       date
0  Fora 2019-08-04
1  Jara 2018-12-17
2  Aura 2018-04-07
```

Comment: спасибо большое, тоже очень неплохой вариант!

Comment: указав `format="%d.%m.%Y"` вы лишаетесь возможости правильно парсить даты такие как: `['31.12.17','31-12-2017']` и т.д. Т.е. парситься будут только даты в формате: `"%d.%m.%Y"`

Comment: @MaxU так никто и не спорит, что встроенный `format` менее гибкий, чем `strftime`.

Comment: @strawdog, я скорее о `pd.to_datetime()` - эта функция очень удачно угадывает форматы даты/времени...

Answer (score 2):

```
In [29]: df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'], dayfirst=True).dt.strftime('%d.%m.%Y')

In [30]: df
Out[30]:
   name        date
0  Fora  08.04.2019
1  Jara  17.12.2018
2  Aura  04.07.2018
```

Comment: MaxU огроменное спасибо! Просто супер!!!

Comment: @Pavel, всегда пожалуйста :)